# Quickblox Error : "Unexpected Signature" while login ChatService in Android

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I had integrated the **Quickblox SDK V2.2.5** in my android application and I found that chat is not functional when we use `SocialProviders` like **Facebook** and **Twitter**.

So, the exact error which didn't let it work occur when we try to login to `ChatService`, after receiving success of all required singleton classes of Quickblox.

***Here following is my code:-***

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final QBSession result, Bundle params) {
        Log.e("QbAuth/onSuccess", "" + result);        

        QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, preference.getFacebookToken(), null, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {            
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                Log.e("Fb Login/onSuccess", "user: " + user.toString());                                                           

                try {
                    user.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
                } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // means you have not created a session before but we have created as we can see.
                }    
                // Lets initialize ChatService if it's not done before.  
                ChatService.initIfNeed(context);

                ChatService.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {        
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {        
                            Log.e("ChatService/onSuccess",
                                    "Logged in to Chat");        
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(final List errors) {        
                            /** It's always been error here while we login **/        
                            Log.e("ChatService Error", "" + errors);                                                                        
                                }
                            });        
                        }
                    });

                try {      
                    // User & password saving.                                                      
                    DataHolder.getDataHolder().setSignInQbUser(
                            user);
                    DataHolder
                            .getDataHolder()
                            .setSignInUserPassword(
                                    BaseService
                                            .getBaseService()
                                            .getToken());
                } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                                                       
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                Log.e("Fb Login/onError", "Error: "
                        + errors);                                                        
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
        Log.e("QbAuth/onError", "" + errors);
    }
});
```

And the Log for same is:-

```
01-20 12:18:37.657 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=25290&auth_key=Mr3GJxYk6krKbQN&nonce=-1682323378&timestamp=1453272517&user[login]=_702514376540831&user[email]=haps%40india.com&user[password]=3731b3f7f4857202ce39516d677baf54bfbbd3aa&signature=6a5c8f377906d5e73852e838b488ef500c499bef  
*** RESPONSE *** a35fe359-229b-4663-b705-67d9e394eb7e ***
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK: STATUS : 422 
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK: HEADERS
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Cache-Control=no-cache
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Connection=keep-alive
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Content-Length=44
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Date=Wed, 20 Jan 2016 06:48:38 GMT
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Server=nginx/1.8.0
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Status=422 Unprocessable Entity
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Request-Id=102f5ea405e66ba568a7a5f5522b65de
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Runtime=0.006373
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK: BODY
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     '{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}'
01-20 12:18:39.187 28040-28040/com.myapp E/ChatService Error: [base Unexpected signature]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to create a session with user's params like login, password and email

can you choose one identity param (login or email) and try with it, don't need to pass both of them

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is no need to create a User session while logging in to Chat. I was creating the session again with user privileges whereas i already had one while "signInUsingSocialProvider".

Comment: Can you help me with this another one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920679/qucikblox-error-bad-authentication-data-for-twitter-login-in-android