# Qucikblox Error: [Bad Authentication data] for twitter login in Android

Tags: android, twitter, quickblox, quickblox-android

I had integrated the **Quickblox SDK V2.2.5** in my android application to work with `Social Integration` **Twitter** but it throws error: **'{"errors":["Bad Authentication data"]}'**

Here following is my code:-

```
// If in the below code I use static TOKEN & TOKEN-SECRET generated by my iOS app then it works well, whereas it is not working with Android generated TOKEN & its SECRET.

QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.TWITTER,
    preferences.getTwitterToken().trim(),
    preferences.getTwitterTokenSecret().trim(),
    new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
            Log.d("Login was successful", "user: " + user.toString());          
            }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.e("Twitter Login", "Error: " + errors);                                        
        }
    });
```

and here is it's shown Log:-

```
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: =========================================================
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: === REQUEST ==== 3d0e6877-35d5-44f6-8ed3-9e4f397635a5 ===
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: REQUEST
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: HEADERS
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QB-SDK=Android 2.2.5
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QB-Token=6dfb07e386b0ea3a1c9032ce797a766177ec57dd
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: PARAMETERS
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     provider=twitter
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     keys[token]=3147189640-RtvTcJ2rG2gNs3CqRUkFjyEnUQU0iKgvCCYiMYQ
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     keys[secret]=BLiq0J2IUT8oYXAne45wm3ULnD5T2Muea10VteIXeW2lW
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: INLINE
01-21 15:13:44.649 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json?provider=twitter&keys[token]=3147189640-RtvTcJ2rG2gNs3CqRUkFjyEnUQU0iKgvCCYiMYQ&keys[secret]=BLiq0J2IUT8oYXAne45wm3ULnD5T2Muea10VteIXeW2lW
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: *** RESPONSE *** 3d0e6877-35d5-44f6-8ed3-9e4f397635a5 ***
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: STATUS : 422 
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: HEADERS
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Cache-Control=no-cache
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Connection=keep-alive
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Content-Length=38
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Date=Thu, 21 Jan 2016 09:43:47 GMT
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2016-01-21 11:42:37 UTC
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Server=nginx/1.8.0
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     Status=422 Unprocessable Entity
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Request-Id=950c35c1ccb0d6d9d15b4de2ec11e781
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-Runtime=0.171756
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK: BODY
01-21 15:13:46.759 31938-31938/com.myapp D/QBASDK:     '{"errors":["Bad Authentication data"]}'
01-21 15:13:46.779 31938-31938/com.myapp E/Twitter Login: Error: [Bad Authentication data]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824994/bad-authentication-data-quickblox-android] link may help you . I was getting the same issue while doing facebook login in android .

Comment: @AndroidDev, I have the correct token and token-secret here as the same credentials are functional on any other Twitter app to make post & fetch feeds but not working for the case of Quickblox.

Comment: Then it can be the issue of QuickBlox Backend .